# Error when attempting to run Google Colab Deforum Stable Diffusion with a local GPU -- ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'helpers.save_images'

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, stable-diffusion

I'm attempting to run Deforum in Google Colab (https://colab.research.google.com/github/deforum-art/deforum-stable-diffusion/blob/main/Deforum_Stable_Diffusion.ipynb).

I was able to successfully get Jupyter installed and the GPU to successfully connect. However, when attempting to run the Environment Setup, I'm encountering the following error:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'helpers.save_images', which appears to be referencing line 57: 57 from helpers.save_images import get_output_folder

Any ideas what I may need to do or install to resolve the issue?

Thank you!